# I need to pass by parameter one only of several attributes of a class

Tags: java, syntax, parameters

I have a class called `Posicion` with two attributes, and i need to pass through parameters only one of these attributes from `Posicion` to class called `Caballo`.
Constructor method from `Caballo` has to accept one parameter of type `Posicion`, but only one of its attributes, specifically parameter called `columna`.
I have a syntax problem, i mean.

I try to put in constructor method of `Caballo` class this one:
`Caballo(Color color, Posicion.columna)` but obviously it gave me an error.

Posicion class:

```
public class Posicion {

    private int fila;
    private char columna;

    Posicion (int fila, char columna){

        if (fila < 1 || fila > 8 || columna < 'a' || columna > 'h') {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Valores fuera de rango");
        }else {
            this.fila=fila;
            this.columna=columna;
        }

    }

    Posicion (Posicion p){

        fila=p.fila;
        columna=p.columna;

    }

    public boolean equals(Posicion fc_A, Posicion fc_B) {

        if (fc_A.fila == fc_B.fila && fc_A.columna == fc_B.columna) {
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    public void setFila(int fila) {

        if (fila < 1 || fila > 8) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Los números de fila"
                    + "deben estar comprendidos entre 1 y 8 ambos inclusive");
        }else {
            this.fila=fila;
        }

    }

    public int getFila() {
        return this.fila;
    }

    public void setColumna(char columna) {

        if (columna < 'a' || columna > 'h') {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Las columnas deben estar comprendidas entre las letras"
                    + "a y h");
        }else {
            this.columna=columna;
        }
    }

    public char getColumna() {
        return columna;
    }

    public String toString() {

        String mensaje="El caballo se encuentra en la posición fila: " + fila + " "
                + "columna: " + columna;

        return mensaje;

    }

}
```

Caballo class till constructor third constructor method:

```
public class Caballo {

    private Color color;
    private Posicion posicion;

    Caballo(){
        posicion.setFila(8);
        posicion.setColumna('b');
    }

    Caballo(Color color){

        this.color=color;

        if(this.color==Color.BLANCO) {

            this.posicion.setFila(1);
            this.posicion.setColumna('b');

        }else if (this.color==Color.NEGRO) {

            this.posicion.setFila(8);
            this.posicion.setColumna('b');

        }

    }

    Caballo(Color color, Posicion.columna){ <-- This is the error

        this.color=color;
        this.posicion=columna;

        if(this.posicion.)

    }
```

I have a syntax error. 
Thanks a lot!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You've not specified a type and variable name for the second parameter:

```
Caballo(Color color, Posicion.columna){ <-- This is the error
```

I'm guessing you want a space:

```
Caballo(Color color, Posicion columna){ <-- This is the error
```

Answer (score 0):

You put a dot between `Posicion` and `columna`, replace it with a space.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the dot... assuming columna is a Posicion

```
Caballo(Color color, Posicion columna){ <-- This is the error

    this.color=color;
    this.posicion=columna;

    if(this.posicion.)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like

```
Caballo(Color color, Posicion posicion){ <-- This is the error

    this.color=color;
    this.posicion.setColumna(posicion.columna);
```

Note: here you are actually passing the whole object but choosing the one attribute (columna) to assign.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone. I have not been able to explain myself well, so i apologize. The type of attribute 'columna' is char and y try to put parameter columna as char and it seems to be working, i'ḿ not sure but, at least, doesn't give me a syntax error.

I wrote this:

```
> Caballo(Color color, char columna){ <-- Not an error with char type

        this.color=color;
        this.posicion.setColumna(columna);
```

Very thanks again for everyone.

P.S: Sorry for my English.